# Resize Move Partitions on Dual Boot System

Tags: gparted

I would like to be able to adjust the partitions shown below. Specifically, I want to add an additional 10GB from the unallocated space to /dev/sda5 (Ubuntu install). I will then format the remaining unallocated space as NTFS so it can be shared data between Windows and Ubuntu.

I am unable to increase the size of /dev/sda5 - I am only able to shrink it.

Any assistance would be greately appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That picture is so small, if possible could you enlarge and repost? Also before messing with re-sizing partitions it is highly recommended to back up data. With dual boot (Windows especially) it is **extremely** important due to how the system deals with partitions and drives. Also prior to removing your sda5 you may wish to be careful as it looks like it most likely holds booting data (as the mount point is /). You will need to unmount it first to modify the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's recommended to backup your data before you proceed.

You need to boot from a Live CD or Live USB (otherwise you can't modify the /dev/sda5 partition since it's your root partition) and run GParted. The following steps should be:

- enlarge the extended partition (/dev/sda3): I recommend here to use all available space;
- move /dev/sda7 to the right by 10 GiB;
- move /dev/sda6 to the right by 10 GiB;
- enlarge /dev/sda5, adding 10 GiB to it;
- create a new partition to exchange between Ubuntu and Windows (NTFS).

Comment: Great answer - worked perfectly, thank you! I was missing your first step... enlarging the extended partition, which in hindsight seems so obvious that you have to expand the container before you can moved/expand one of its members. Thank you again. One question, I'm now left with an additional unallocated partition of 1.00MiB that is in /dev/sda3. If I delete that partition, will it be included in the larger unallocated partition (that will soon become a shared NTFS partition)?