# How to allocate free space from Window sda, and append to Ubuntu's partition the additional free space?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

This is what I see when I run gparted.

[image]

I have just installed Ubuntu, and found out that this system is really cool. So, I decided to increase the size of Ubuntu, (sda6) as indicated here [Resize Move Partitions on Dual Boot System](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504420/resize-move-partitions-on-dual-boot-system?newreg=d8522e230d10409c8cb7f09fc3f58b79) I was gonna use this link on the left, but there was no free, or unallocated, memory available for me to append to sda6.

Is it possible to reduce the size of Windows (sda4), and append it to sda6? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you're asking about is disk space, not memory. Anyway, you need to do three steps in GParted:

1. Shrink /dev/sda4, and make sure the new free space ends up after it
2. Move /dev/sda5 to the beginning of the new free space, leaving it the same size
3. Grow /dev/sda6 into the free space before it

Also, I note you appear to be booted into your system in that screenshot. You should reboot from a live CD/USB to do those operations.

Comment: Ok thanks. And i have another question. As you can see from the screenshot, there are many different sda. I don't know enough to tell, but do they include any unnecessary ones not being used? I see that normally, other people only have about 6 sda files even after installing dualboot. I am not sure if this is a normal case

Comment: Your computer manufacturer likely added their own recovery partitions in addition to what Windows has.

Comment: Much better is to resize your window partition from windows disk manager.. I have been haveing problems doing this operation from linux in the past..

Comment: @AndreaSimonetti resizing Windows partitions from Linux works fine for most people. You're the exception; there's nothing inherently better about doing it from Windows.