# Unable to increase partition size using gparted on Ubuntu 16

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, partitioning

I have a 50GB partition (sda10) that I want to merge with an existing partition of 172GB (sda4). How do I go about it?

The partitions are not contiguous. I am new to Ubuntu and don't want to mess up my system badly.

[image]

Comment: The short answer is do not do anything of the sort you're thinking about. Partitions cannot be merged even if contiguous; one can be deleted and the other extended/expanded to use the now unallocated space but that's it

Comment: @MichaelBay I meant to extend/expand. Is this not possible?

Comment: @user110327It's not possible without an extreme risk of messing up your system

Comment: What you could try is setting the new partition to mount itself automatically and put your home folder into it. I know its possible and not too hard to achieve. I put you some links : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving and https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/ but this actually doesn't answer directly to your question. It's only what I would do in your case :)

Comment: he's talking about merging two ntfs partitions, this isn't a ubuntu question

Comment: If the partition is new (has no files on it), it can be deleted, intervening partitions moved, and the partition that should be grown can then be grown. Because two of the intervening partitions are Ubuntu partitions, this *is* a valid AskUbuntu question, IMHO; however, it's also a duplicate; see [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603436/gparted-how-to-move-partition-to-extend-the-size) or [this one,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504420/resize-move-partitions-on-dual-boot-system) for instance. (There are a ton more.)